# Area and volume of a sphere in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Now in this problem you have to use the C code as a reference to create the scheme code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const double PI = 3.14159265;

double areac(double d) {
    double a;
    a = PI*(d/2)*(d/2);
    return a;
}

double volumec(double d, double h) {
    double a, v;
    a = areac(d);   // call areac() here
    v = a*h;
    return v;
}

double TotalVolume() {
    double v1, v2, v3, v4, v5;
    v1 = volumec(1, 1);
    v2 = volumec(2, 2);
    v3 = volumec(3, 3);
    v4 = volumec(4, 4);
    v5 = volumec(5, 5);
    return v1+v2+v3+v4+v5;
}

void main() {
    double v;
    v = TotalVolume();
    printf("%f\n",v);
}
```

Now I have written code in Scheme and it is as follows:

```
(define PI 3.14159265)

(define areac
  (lambda(d)
    (* PI (expt (/ d 2) 2))))

(write"Areac: ")
 (areac 5)
 (newLine)

 (define volumec
   (lambda (d h)
     (* (* (expt (/ d 2) 2) h) PI)))

 (write"Volumec: ")
 (volumec 5 5)
 (newLine)

 (define TotalVolume
   (lambda()
     (+ (volumec  1 1) (volumec 2 2) (volumec 3 3) (volumec 4 4) (volumec 5 5))))

 (define main 
   (lambda ()
     (* (TotalVolume) 1)))

 (write"Total Volume: ")
 (main)
 (newLine)
```

Now instead of writing formula in `volumec` I have to reference `areac` in the `volumec` and then run it.

Comment: You might look into the Commutative Property of Multiplication (http://bit.ly/14ky8Zh)

Answer (score 2):

Then just call `areac` from `volumec`:

```
(define volumec
  (lambda (d h)
    (* h (areac d))))
```

Explanation: first, note that your current implementation of `volumec` is equivalent to this, by virtue of the commutative property of multiplication:

```
(* h (* PI (expt (/ d 2) 2)))
```

Now it's a matter of simply replacing the code that was already calculated in `areac`:

```
(* PI (expt (/ d 2) 2))
```

With a call to `areac`, noticing that the only missing value that must be passed as parameter is `d`:

```
(areac d)
```

After that, as seen in the original formula in C, the only thing left to do is multiplying by `h`, and we're all set:

```
(* h (areac d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some nitpicks.

```
 (define TotalVolume
   (lambda()
     (let ((do-it (lambda (x) (volumec x x))))   
      (reduce + 0 
       (map do-it (list 1 2 3 4 5)))))
```

When you find yourself typing the same thing over and over you're acting as a human compiler, one way to avoid it is by using higher order functions.

```
 (define main 
   (lambda ()
     (let ((v (TotalVolume)))
      (display v))))
```

Be aware the difference between what is returned to the REPL and what is actually displayed as output. Unless you are using a function like, display, write, show, format, or print... what is displayed on screen is a side effect of the REPL and not actual output from the program. Also `write` is used when you want to be able to `read` it back into a function in the same form as when saving a data structure to a file, `display` is generally what's used to display to be read by a human.

Use the let special form let to define local variables in a function body.

Comment: `(eq 'total-volume 'TotalVolume) ==> #f`